# RxSwift Disposable property isDisposed always false or Disposable closure newer called to cancel worker task

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, rx-swift

I need have some worker task in my observable which I want to cancel when there are no any subscriptions to my observable. But even when my observable have no subscriptions and even I got onDisposed event. The worker task in my observable continue it's execution while it must not because it depends on isDisposed property of my disposable but it is always false.

Here my code:

```
Observable<Void>.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let disposable = BooleanDisposable(isDisposed: false)

        Thread(block: {
            while (!disposable.isDisposed) {
                print("Next")
                observer.onNext(())
                sleep(1)

            }

            observer.onCompleted()
            print("Done")

        }).start()

        return disposable
        }.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            print("onNext")
        }, onCompleted: {
            print("onCompleted")
        }) {
            print("onDisposed")
    }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

And output:

```
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext 
onDisposed
Completed
Next
Next
Next
... and so on
```

While I am expecting something like that:

```
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext
Next
onNext 
onDisposed
Completed
Done
```

What am I doing wrong or I just don't understand Disposables and Observables properly?

I'am using RxSwift 4.5.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please attach the code where you actually use the created observable. Create subscriptions or whatever

Comment: This code is in viewDidLoad method of my viewController it just have DisposeBag and viewDidLoad method. Subscription is at the end of my code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default of `false` is incorrect. It should be `true`. But if you don't make the disposable weak then you don't need a default.

```
Observable<Void>.create { observer -> Disposable in
    let disposable = BooleanDisposable(isDisposed: false)

    Thread(block: { [disposable] in
            while (!disposable.isDisposed) {
                observer.onNext(())
                sleep(1)
            }
        })
        .start()

    return disposable
    }
    .debug("here")
    .take(5)
    .subscribe()
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is not in default value (I have made the edit it my question to prevent misunderstanding). The main problem is the disposable property isDisposed newer becomes  true even if I manually call dispose() on my subscription.

Comment: Check the edit you made to your code and you will find that `disposable.isDisposed` *does* become true. Your problem was that you weren't retaining it long enough to read the value.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I really was the problem with  retaining disposable long enough and default value led to confusion about correct exit condition.